# What is the best way to extract only hex value for all fields to JSON with Wireshark/TShark

Tags: wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I want to get information I have with Wireshark (the GUI), the information I want are for each packets its layers with all fields and their hexadecimal values. I want to get it to transform each packet into a JSON with this structure:

```
{
    "pcap_file": pcap_file,
    "number": paquet number (this first column in Wireshark GUI),
    "sniff_time" : sniff time
    "layers": { 
        layer_name: {
            field_name: field's raw value,
            .......
        },
        ......
    ]
}
```

I tried while few hours to do with the pyshark library in python. I almost done it but the thing is sometimes I don't have some information about the last layer.

For example for a LDAP packet with in the LDAP layer two fields "SASL Buffer Length" and "SASL Buffer" I had only the "SASL Buffer". So for this example I could build "SASL Buffer" using the layer's raw data on subtract "SASL BUffer Length"'s raw data. But with a lot of other examples with more missing fields, I couldn't because this library doesn't provide the order of fields.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to have all this information (all fields, with their order and their raw values, and for each layer) as we have in the GUI.

I saw there is maybe these ways:

-[Write a C++ program and use tshark and use JSON option](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/12850/command-line-tshark-json-and-packet-details-all-expanded/)

-[Write a Lua script to dissect packet](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua#lua-in-wireshark)

-[Export data as JSON](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html)

But honestly I'm pretty lost, for all documentation/answers I did read, I don't see way to get raw values as I want and have with the GUI

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to have what I need:

```
tshark -T pdml -r your_pcap > your_pcap.pdml
```

The thing is tshark will give a lot of information so for those who want to do like me, you have to do a script to filter information you only want. Indeed it's impossible according to documentation to select information we want keep when we use `-T pdml` option (or I didn't see it ahah)

Also for a **100MB** pcap, I had a **2.8GB** pdml file so if you have big pcap, think about split it into smaller pcaps with editcap